# Getting latlong from address using google geocoding

Tags: c#

I am using google geocoding api to get latitude and longitude from address.But it gives an exception

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

The code is as below:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = GetGeocodeUri(address);
string[] geocodeInfo = client.DownloadString(uri).Split(',');
return new Coordinate(Convert.ToDecimal(geocodeInfo[2]),convert.ToDecimal(geocodeInfo[3]));
```

The exception comes from line 3 at the time of "downloadstring".
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Was this working before and now stopped working?  GeoCoding has usage limits and can return a 403 if your going over those limits.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

snip it:

> HTTP 403 response
>
> Requests to the web services may also receive a HTTP 403 (Forbidden)
>   error. In most cases, this is due to an invalid URL signature. To
>   verify this, remove the client and signature parameters and try again:
>
> If the response is HTTP 200 (OK), the signature was the problem.  This
>   is not related to usage limits; see Generating Valid Signatures in the
>   Web Services chapter of the Maps API for Business documentation for
>   details. If the response is still a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error, the
>   signature was not necessarily the problem, it may be related to usage
>   limits instead.  This typically means your access to the web service
>   has been blocked on the grounds that your application has been
>   exceeding usage limits for too long or otherwise abused the web
>   service. Please contact Google Enterprise Support if you encounter
>   this issue. Requests to all web services require URL signatures.
>   Requests will also be rejected with a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error when
>   including the client parameter but missing the signature parameter, or
>   vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loc = await GetLocation("central park");
```

---

```
public static async Task<GeoCoordinate> GetLocation(string address)
{
    string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string json = await  wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url + address);
        dynamic result = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync(json);
        var loc = result.results[0].geometry.location;
        return new GeoCoordinate((double)loc.lat, (double)loc.lng);
    }
}
```